# Java Regex: Remove Everything After Last Instance Of Character

Tags: java, regex

Say I have a string:

```
/first/second/third
```

And I want to remove everything after the last instance of / so I would end up with:

```
/first/second
```

What regular expression would I use? I've tried:

```
String path = "/first/second/third";
String pattern = "$(.*?)/";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern2);
Matcher m = r.matcher(path);
if(m.find()) path = m.replaceAll("");
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why use a regex at all here?  Look for the last `/` character with [`lastIndexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29).  If it's found, then use [`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) to extract everything before it.

Comment: +1, though, I think the OP wants to extract everything _before_ it.

Comment: @damo You're right; I've updated my answer (and substring link).

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean like this

```
s = s.replaceAll("/[^/]*$", "");
```

Or better if you are using paths

```
File f = new File(s);
File dir = f.getParent(); // works for \ as well.
```

Comment: You mean `replaceAll` I think.

Comment: @arshajii Yes, replace() doesn't do regex.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a string that contains your character (whether a supplemental code-point or not), then you can use `Pattern.quote` and match the inverse charset up to the end thus:

```
String myCharEscaped = Pattern.quote(myCharacter);
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^" + myCharEscaped + "]*\\z");
```

should do it, but really you can just use `lastIndexOf` as in

```
myString.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf(myCharacter) + 1)
```

To get a code-point as a string just do

```
new StringBuilder().appendCodePoint(myCodePoint).toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite the answers avoiding regex Pattern and Matcher, it's useful for performance (compiled patterns) and it'still pretty straightforward and worth mastering.  :)

Not sure why you have "$" up front. Try either:

1. Matching starting group

   ```
   String path = "/first/second/third";
   String pattern = "^(.*)/";  // * = "greedy": maximum string from start to last "/"
   Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern2);
   Matcher m = r.matcher(path);
   if (m.find()) path = m.group();
   ```
2. Stripping tail match:

   ```
   String path = "/first/second/third";
   String pattern = "/(.*?)$)/"; // *? = "reluctant": minimum string from last "/" to end
   Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern2);
   Matcher m = r.matcher(path);
   if (m.find()) path = m.replace("");
   ```